# Linq contains confusion

Tags: c#, linq

I have noticed something odd with linq and the Contains method.  It seems to get confused on which Contains method to call.

```
if (myString.Contains(strVar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  // Code here                  
}
```

The above code doesn't compile with the following error:

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

If I remove the using linq statement it is happy with the contains (but brakes all the linq code).

What is the correct syntax to tell the compiler I want to use the String.Contains method and not Linqs?

Cheers

Comment: that title is more fun when you read it wrong.

Comment: Ha Ha true.  I guess there was more wisdom in the title than the question itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because there's no `String.Contains(string, StringComparison)` method defined in the BCL and the compiler tries to use an extension method. There's only [String.Contains(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method defined.

Comment: FYI: It was added in [.NET 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and [.NET Core 2.1+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-2.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_System_StringComparison_)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct syntax to tell the compiler I want to use the `String.Contains` method and not Linqs?

There is no overload of [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx) that accepts a [`StringComparision`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx). You might want to use [`String.IndexOf(string, StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx):

```
// s is string
if(s.IndexOf(strVar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be because the `string.Contains` method takes only one parameter (a `string`; there is no overload of `string.Contains` that takes a `StringComparison` value), while the `Enumarable.Contains` extension method takes two. However, the parameters that you supply do not fit the expected input types, so the compiler gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

As Darin Dimitrov said, `String.Contains(string, StringComparison)` does not exist as a method for the `String` type.

`System.Linq.Enumerable` however does contain such a signature. And a `string` is also an `IEnumerable<char>`, that's why the compiler gets confused. You would actually be able to leverage Linq and compile if you replaced the StringCompar-**ison** with an ICompar-**er** of `Char`:

```
if (myString.Contains(strVar, Comparer<Char>.Default))
{
    // Code here                  
}
```

Comment: string is an `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: This will not work. `string` does not implement `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Coming here a bit late, but this still doesn't work. `Comparer<T>` *does not* implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`, so the type on the second argument is still wrong. Seems that there's no `char` equivalent to `StringComparer`, so you'd probably have to implement your own comparer if you want to use this extension method